# Calling a Class Method without initializing the class in Python

Tags: java, python, class, methods

I'm trying to re-write this Java code into Python. This is the Java code (works perfectly):

```
public class Main {
    private static Pager demandPager;
    private static ArrayList<Process> runningProcesses = new ArrayList<Process>();
    private static ArrayList<Process> finishedProcesses = new ArrayList<Process>();
    private static int numProcesses;
    private static int numRefPerProcess;

    private static int clock;
    private final static int QUANTUM = 3;

    private static File randNum;
    private static Scanner randReader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readInput(args);
        initializeRandNums();

        int prIdx = 0;
        while(runningProcesses.size() > 0) {
            Process p = runningProcesses.get(prIdx);
            for (int ref = 0; ref < QUANTUM; ref++) {
                demandPager.processRef(p, clock, randReader);
                p.setCurrentReference(p.c

alcNextReference(randReader));
                p.incrRefsMade(); 

            clock++;

            if (p.getRefsMade() == numRefPerProcess) {
                finishedProcesses.add(p);
                runningProcesses.remove(p);
                prIdx--;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prIdx == numProcesses-1) {
            prIdx = 0;
        }
        else {
            prIdx++;
        }

    }
    printOutput(args);
}

public static void readInput(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 6) {
        System.out.println("Please input the machine size, page size, process size, job mix, number of references per process, and the replacement algorithm.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    demandPager = new Pager(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    Page.setSize(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    Process.setSize(Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
    initializeProcesses(args[3]);
    numRefPerProcess = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
    demandPager.setReplacementAlgo(args[5]);
}
```

> This is the Page Class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Page {
    private static int size;
    private int timeEvicted;
    private int timeLoaded;
    private int timeLastUsed;

    private ArrayList<Integer> referencedWords;



private int frameId;
    private int pageId;
    private Process ownerProcess;
    private boolean ifLoaded; 

    public Page(int frame) {
        frameId = frame;
        pageId = -1;
        timeEvicted = 0;
    timeLoaded = 0;
    ifLoaded = false;
    ownerProcess = null;
    referencedWords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public void initalize(Process owner, int pgId, int refdWord, boolean ifLoad) {
    ownerProcess = owner;
    pageId = pgId;
    addRefdWord(refdWord);
    ifLoaded = ifLoad;
}

public static void setSize(int s) {
    size = s;
}

public void setPageId(int p) {
    pageId = p;
}
```

My attempt at converting it to Python is as follows:

```
from Process import Process
from Page import Page as Page
from Pager import Pager
from FrameTable import FrameTable 
import sys
#store random numbers in a list
r = open('random.txt')
l = []
for c in r:
    l.append(int(c))
runningProcesses = []
finishedProcesses = []
def main():
    #read input
    machineSize = int(sys.argv[1])
    pageSize = int(sys.argv[2])
    processSize = int(sys.argv[3])
    jobMix = int(sys.argv[4])
    numOfRefPerProcess = int(sys.argv[5])
    replacementAlgo = (sys.argv[6])
    demandPager = Pager(machineSize, pageSize)
    Page.setSize(pageSize)
    Process.setSize(processSize)
    setProc(jobMix)
    demandPager.setAlg(replacementAlgo)

    index = 0
    while(runningProcesses.size() > 0):
        p = runningProcesses.get(index)
        for i in range(3):
            demandPager.processRef(p, clock, randReader)
            p.setCurrentReference(p.calcNextReference(randReader))
            p.incrRefsMade()

            clock+=1

            if (p.getRefsMade() == numRefPerProcess):
                finishedProcesses.add(p)
                runningProcesses.remove(p)
                index-=1
                break
        if (index == numProcesses-1):
            index = 0
        else:
            index+=1
    print "print ng....."
    printOutput(args)
```

> The Class Page:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frameId = frame
        self.pageId = -1
        self.timeEvicted = 0
        self.timeLoaded = 0
        self.ifLoaded = False
        self.ownerProcess = 0
        self.referencedWords = []
        self.size = 0

    def initalize(owner, pgId, refdWord, ifLoad):
        self.ownerProcess = owner
        self.pageId = pgId
        addRefdWord(refdWord)
        self.ifLoaded = ifLoad

    @classmethod
    def setSize(cls, s):
        size = s

    def setPageId(self,p):
        self.pageId = p
```

My problem is that every time I try to run this code, I get this error: 
TypeError: unbound method setSize() must be called with Process instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

I'm not sure why this is. Is this just not legal in Python or am I missing something?

Comment: Please post the exact error, traceback and all.

Comment: Not sure about the error, but regardless, your `setSize` method in python does absolutely nothing. Perhaps iyou want `cls.size = s`

Comment: Wait, are you on Python 2? If so, to use `classmethod` you need to inherit from `object` explicitly, otherwise, it is an old-style class, and the decorator won't work correctly.

Comment: I’d guess you’re running this with an old-style class in Python 2.x. Upgrade (or inherit from object)!

Answer (score 1):

Python has no exact equivalent to Java's static variables.  But it does have class variables that are declared within the class body but outside of any member function.  You access these variables using the class name in front of the "." instead of an instance.  What you want is something like this:

```
class Page:
    size = 0    # Moved out of __init__
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frameId = frame
        self.pageId = -1
        self.timeEvicted = 0
        self.timeLoaded = 0
        self.ifLoaded = False
        self.ownerProcess = 0
        self.referencedWords = []

    def initalize(owner, pgId, refdWord, ifLoad):
        self.ownerProcess = owner
        self.pageId = pgId
        addRefdWord(refdWord)
        self.ifLoaded = ifLoad

    @staticmethod   # Changed from classmethod
    def setSize(s):
        Page.size = s   # Syntax changed

    def setPageId(self,p):
        self.pageId = p
```

In Python it's not necessarily considered good style to provide setter functions.  If you removed the `setSize` function entirely, client code could simply set the size using `Page.size = s` rather than a function call.  There is little to be gained by writing a lot of setter functions.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a similar way I can change the getter functions?

Comment: You don't need to change from a class method, once it's a new-style class they just needed `cls.size = s`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe True for this case but there is a difference when a class is derived from `Page`.